# RestAssured MockMvc add user to session

Tags: rest-assured, spring-test-mvc, spring-cloud-contract

I need to mock session with a user when creating the `RestAssuredMockMvc`

I know that I can add the user while `mockMvc.perform`, but as the tests are generated, I would like to add a session, with a `Principal` in it.

At the moment I am doing 

 `mockMvc.perform(post(URL_TEMPLATE, 5L)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .principal(()-> 2L))`

I would like to somehow manage to do it while creating the RestassuredMockMvc

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EXPLICIT mode and start a normal context - that will be faster. Or just use the setup like presented here - https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#spring-mvc-authentication (I'm talking about autogenerated tests). You can also use the MockMvc authentication setup if you're using RestDOCS + Spring Cloud Contract WireMock